# SSR not working after upgrade from spartacus 3.4 to 4.2

Tags: server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

When upgrading from spartacus 3.4 to 4.2, SSR stopped working. The app always switches back to CSR after the timeout exceeds (no matter how much I increase this timeout value in server.ts).
The app builds sucessfully and there are no errors while loading the app. Also the main.js file in the dist/server dir gets generated correctly and contains the app's content.

Server.ts, app.server.module.ts and ts.configserver.json files are more or less the same than in OOTB spartacus 4.x (and they work fine with spartacus 3.4).

While loading the app, the "app-root" tag stays empty (until CSR starts) and also the transfer state script at the bottom is missing. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: 1. are you using Spartacus' ssr optimization engine? if so, can you enable `debug` option?
2. are there any errors in the ssr console?
3. can you configure `maxRenderTime` and check if there are any errors in the ssr console after the set time expires?
4. it's recommended to avoid using the browser, and use `curl` to issue ssr requests

Comment: Hi - I am using 'ssr optimization engine' and 'debug' option is enabled. Also with `maxRenderTime` I do not get any errors in my node console (just 'Rendering started' and after the defined timeout occurs: 'CSR fallback: rendering in progress' and again after a while 'Rendering was not able to complete. This might cause memory leaks!'). Using curl command returns the proper index.html but, like mentioned above, with empty "app-root" html tags and also the state transfer script is missing.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to server-side render? Is it a home URL? Or PDP, PLP, etc.? Is it the same for each URL?
We would still need more information on this to be able to assist, and any kind of info you may have could help us :)

Comment: It happens for all url's (PDP, PLP, landingpage) running the app locally and also in the cloud... The really strange thing is that there is no error/warning etc. in the node console so it's a bit hard to find the root cause...

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to know where to start. Did you do any customization in the failing pages? Is _any_ page working?

Comment: Currently no page is working in SSR - And we have a lot of customizations in our project - While debugging I kicked out a lot of modules and saw that if I just use a simple dummy headline component as the main app component, SSR works - but as soon as I add the spartacus BaseStorefrontModule (import and export in app.module) SSR breaks again ...

Comment: As we're not seeing this issue in OOTB Spartacus 4.2.x, we can only assume the issue is in your custom code.
We can suggest you to try stripping out custom code step by step on one page (e.g. PDP), and check the results. In that way, you should be able to eventually find the issue. Feel free to come back here if you're looking for an advice on how to solve it.

Comment: Finally we found the issue - a known spartacus issue with a custom i18n config caused this behaviour https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/13643

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue! We are looking into this issue.